# pushwoosh init(); give me error

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, init

I am using phonegap pushwoosh for notification. I follow the instruction but i stack on some place.

i did  as instruction now i have to put the below code in some where

```
function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", initPushwoosh, true);

//rest of the code
}
```

can any one some me some sample how to put the code. i check the sample from pushwoosh but they are using

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
```

Not Body `onload=init();` now i am confused....

I am new on android and phonegap and pushwoosh. please please help me.

Please help me.
Thanking you
Masum

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(function() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, true);
});
```